# repeat playing automatically

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudioplayer

I use below code for play sound

```
NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"01" ofType:@"mp3"]]; 
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
[audioPlayer play];
```

I want to repeat this sound file automatically when it's finish How ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = someNumber;
```

or for "infinite" number of loops:

```
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
player.numberOfLoops = -1;
 [player prepareToPlay];

    [player play];
```