# How to make my music loop (repeat)

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [repeat playing automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560161/repeat-playing-automatically)

How can I loop a sound (my background music)

here is my code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MathMusic" ofType:@"aif"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio= [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
[theAudio play];
```

How can I make it ongoing and if I loop it will it still be playing in the next (or another) view?

Comment: Is your question about iOS or MacOS? Please add the corresponding tag. Futhermore, your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with the development environment XCode. So please remove that tag.

Comment: this app is being developed for iOS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the AVAudioPlayer and set the numberOfLoops property to -1 (infinite).

Answer (score 0):

Setting `numberOfLoops` to a negative value will cause the player to loop until you call `stop`:

[AVAudioPlayer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)