# how to launch mp3 from code in XCode4

Tags: xcode, audio, ios4, mp3

I'm writing an application for iOS4. Is there any fast way to launch an mp3 file from code? I need to loop on an mp3 file as long as the app is running.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [repeat playing automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560161/repeat-playing-automatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the AVAudioPlayer:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc ] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; // infinite loops
[audioPlayer play];
```

This does the job.